# While loop does not recognise if statement and variables?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, project, division

I'm doing a code for a school project and I tried to include a while loop but the if statement that is inside this loop is not recognised and the program does not recognise the variable Correct_Weight under each statement and instead it takes it as 0 which causes a division by zero error.

the code is this:

```
Coin_Grams = 0
Correct_Weight = 0
Difference = 0
Total_Coins_Removed = []
Total_Coins_Added = []
Coins_To_Remove = 0
Coins_To_Add = 0
Number_Of_Bags_Checked = 0
Continue = "y"

print ("Welcome to our program!")

while Continue == "y":
    Type_Of_Coin = input("Please enter the type of coin in the bag")
    break
    if Type_Of_Coin == "1 pence":
        Coin_Grams = 3.56 
        Correct_Weight = Coin_Grams * 100
    elif Type_Of_Coin == "2 pence":
        Coin_Grams = 7.12 
        Correct_Weight = Coin_Grams * 50
    elif Type_Of_Coin == "5 pence":
        Coin_Grams = 3.25
        Correct_Weight = Coin_Grams * 100
    elif Type_Of_Coin == "10 pence":
        Coin_Grams = 6.50
        Correct_Weight = Coin_Grams * 50
    elif Type_Of_Coin == "20 pence":
        Coin_Grams = 5.00
        Correct_Weight = Coin_Grams * 50
    elif Type_Of_Coin == "50 pence":
        Coin_Grams = 8.00
        Correct_Weight = Coin_Grams * 20
    elif Type_Of_Coin == "1 pound":
        Coin_Grams = 9.50
        Correct_Weight = Coin_Grams * 20
    elif Type_Of_Coin == "2 pounds":
        Coin_Grams = 12.00
        Correct_Weight = Coin_Grams * 10
    else:
        print ("Type of coin is wrong please try again")


Current_Weight = int(input("How much does the bag weight?"))

Difference = Current_Weight - Correct_Weight
print ("The difference is" ,Difference, "grams")

if Difference <= 0:
    Coins_To_Add = abs(Difference) / Coin_Grams
    Total_Coins_Add.append(Coins_To_Add)
    print ("You need to add" ,round(Coins_To_Add), "coins")
elif Difference >= 0:
    Coins_To_Remove = Difference / Coin_Grams
    Total_Coins_Removed.append(Coins_To_Remove)
    print ("You need to remove" ,round(Coins_To_Remove), "coins")
else:
    print ("You don't need to remove or add any coins")
Number_Of_Bags_Checked = Number_Of_Bags_Checked + 1

Continue = input("Do you have any more bags to check? please answer as y or n")
print ("\n")

if Continue == "n":
    print("\n")
    print (Number_Of_Bags_Checked,"bags have been checked")
    print ("\n")
    print (Total_Coins_Removed,"coins have been removed in total")
    print ("\n")
    print (Total_Coins_Added,"coins have been added in total")
```

and the error is this:

[image]

Comment: what is that unconditional `break` doing in your while loop?

Comment: You execute `break` right at the top of the loop.

Comment: Please put error messages *in your question as text*. A screenshot can't be searched for.

Comment: okei so, if i remove the break then the Type_Of_Coin input question keeps repeating endlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top, `Coin_Grams` is set to 0:

```
Coin_Grams = 0
```

and you never set it to something else, because you *break out of the loop* immediately:

```
while Continue == "y":
    Type_Of_Coin = input("Please enter the type of coin in the bag")
    break
```

It doesn't matter what other code is in the loop past that point, because you told Python to ignore it.

So you end up with `Coint_Grams` still set to `0` and that gives you a division by zero exception.

Put the `break` at the *end* of the loop, and use `continue` in the `else:` block:

```
while True:
    Type_Of_Coin = input("Please enter the type of coin in the bag")
    if Type_Of_Coin == "1 pence":
        # etc.

    else:
        print ("Type of coin is wrong please try again")
        # when you get here the type of coin was incorrect, start again
        continue

    break  # when you get here the type of coin was correct, so break out
```

I also replaced the `while` condition; your `==` test is always true, and you don't need to change the value of the `Continue` variable, so you may as well just test for `while True` here.

Comment: okei so, if i remove the break then the Type_Of_Coin input question keeps repeating endlessly.

Comment: @CodyDenisa: I have long since added how to solve that; move the `break` to the *end* and make sure it is not reached when the coin type entry is wrong by adding `continue` to the `else` block.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok I have done what you've shown me and it works well, it tells me the difference, how many is need to remove or add, BUT when I answer that I want to continue to the Continue question, nothing happens, any ideas why? Because I want the program to repeat again if the user wants to check another bag the while loop should repeat again with the Type_Of_Coin question

Comment: @CodyDenisa: you'll need to put everything inside another loop. Indent your code, put another `while True` at the top, and if the user states they don't want to continue, use `break` to end that loop.

Comment: I tried but nothing happens still if the user wants to continue.

Comment: @CodyDenisa: I can't see what you tried or help you further in comments. Sounds like you need to ask a *new* question.